# Mass in calculating centrifugal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force

I am having trouble understanding the "mass" in a spring-loaded system rotating at a distance $r$ from the axis of rotation, used in the equation $F = mr\omega^2$. If the spring is attached at one end to a fixed part and the other part is attached to a mass that is free to move ONLY in the direction of applied force (centrifugal force) should the mass of spring be included in the equation $F = mr\omega^2$ or only the mass of the body has to be considered?

[image]

Comment: "*free to move ONLY in the direction of applied force (centrifugal force)*" Note that you mean *only along the dimension of the applied force*. The applied force is not a centrifugal force and it is in fact pulling inwards, not pushing outwards.

Comment: thank you for the reply. The issue is to find the distance traveled by the mass in the direction of force when it is rotated. I have drawn some more info for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the spring has non-neglible mass the problem becomes quite complicated and no formula of the sort you write will be applicable. The spring will be streteched by different amounts in its different parts and you will need to solve a differential equation to find the total exptension.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to calculate the force for.

- Do you want to calculate the force pulling in the object? Then use the object's mass only.
- Do you want to calculate the force pulling in the whole system (spring and object), then in theory you want to use the total mass of spring-plus-object. You will get a problem now, though, since not every point in this system has the same angular velocity $\omega$. Therefor not every point feels the same force.

How to solve this depends on what you are looking for. Are you looking for the extension $r$ that corresponds to a specific angular speed, then you might have do an integration through the spring forces along the spring.